# Active Record: ordering finds and also returning nulls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, find

I want to find a ordered list of runners by their results.

models

```
class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :runners, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Runner < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :race
  has_one :result, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :runner
end
```

trying to use something like this

```
ordered_runners = race.runners.all(:include => :result, :order => 'results.position ASC')
```

position is their finishing position ie [1,2,3,4....]

but if a result is missing (nil) then the runner is not included. Is there a way to do this and return all runners?

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Runners without Results are not included because `:include` only brings in the data minimizing the number of queries to avoid N+1 hits to the db. You want to do an outer `:join` to include all runners no matter if they have a result or not.

```
ordered_runners = race.runners.all(:joins => "left outer join results on runners.id = results.runner_id", :order => 'results.position ASC')
```

Check this code based on your migration column/table names and your database.

Answer (score -1):

This should return the runners with a null result:

```
race.runners.all(:include => :result, :conditions => "results IS NULL",  :order => 'results.position ASC')
```